# Facebook like button disappeared

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Please help.

I want to add a facebook like button for my facebook page on my website, but I cannot do it because the fb like button does not show up.

When I go to the like button configurator https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator , and enter the url of my fb page in the 'URL to like', the like button does not show up. Even if I copy & paste the code generated from the like button configurator to my website, the like button does not show up on my website.

But if I enter a different facebook page in the 'URL to like', the like button shows up and everything works as expected.

I noticed this issue about 10 days ago.

Before that, there were no issues and the like button for my fb page was visible on my website and also in the like button configurator https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator.

I contacted facebook about this issue many time but they don't answer.

Why is my like button not visible anymore?

[image]

Comment: Have the same issue, after liking, button disappear for everyone.

Comment: Same issue here. Some pages appear, some pages disappear...

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue today. We recognized that the `og:url` didn´t match the `data-href` of the like button and so the button wasn´t shown at all (even though it was rendered) - This is also mentioned in the official documentation.

Maybe this helps someone else.

Comment: Not working for me, have `og:url`, `data-href` & `canonical`, all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently investigating the capabilities of Facebook API, like/share/comment of public posts from a public pages, for a client. I also noticed this problem. I think that this is related to a fact that Facebook removed the option to like page posts without the page access token that must be granted to your app by a page owner. If you try to do it from the Facebook API you will get the following error:
"(#3) Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens"

I was able to get like button for my page itself, but as soon as I enter the url to some of the page's posts, the button disappears. You shouldn't suppose to have problem with the share button, but if you try to use an integrated version of like+share button, if the like doesn't work, you will lose the share button too.

Here is (only) the share button Configurator:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button